# Exponential Function Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

Let
$$f(x) = \frac{x - \sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{3} + 1}.$$
What is $f^{2012}(x)$, where $f^{2012}$ is the function we get when we compose $f$ with itself 2012 times?

---

I can't just do direct calculations, I need to manipulate the function.  But how?  I'm really confused right now.

Comment: Did you try $f^2$ and see if you can find any similarities with $f$?

Comment: It's worth looking up "Möbius transformations" to understand what this has to do with linear algebra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that $f^3(x) = x$.  To see that you just have to plug in the previous $f$ and simplify the expressions.

$$f^1(x) = \frac{x+\sqrt{3}}{x\sqrt{3}+1} \\
f^2(x) = \frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{1-x\sqrt{3}} \\
f^3(x) = x
$$
Next, notice that $2012 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. So 
$$
f^{2012}(x) = f^2(x) = \frac{x-\sqrt{3}}{1-x\sqrt{3}}
$$

Comment: Love it!  Clear and precise!

Answer (score 0):

We certainly don't want to plug the function into itself $2012$ times, so we test the first few to see if there is a pattern:

$f^1(x) = f(x) = \frac{x-\sqrt3}{x\sqrt3+1}$
$f^2(x) = \frac{\left(\frac{x-\sqrt3}{x\sqrt3+1}\right)-\sqrt3}{\left(\frac{x-\sqrt3}{x\sqrt3+1}\right)\sqrt3+1} = \frac{x+\sqrt3}{1-x\sqrt3}$
$f^3(x) = \frac{\left(\frac{x-\sqrt3}{x\sqrt3+1}\right)+\sqrt3}{1-\left(\frac{x-\sqrt3}{x\sqrt3+1}\right)\sqrt3} = x $

This means that $f^4(x) = f(x)$, so the terms repeat every $3$.

$2012/3=670 \text{ remainder } 2$, so $f^{2012}=f^2 = \boxed{\frac{x-\sqrt3}{1-x\sqrt3}}$.